# How to notify after multiple AJAX call completes

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 3 ajax calls on my page. Second ajax call will call on success of first and third ajax call will call on success of second. Each response returns multiple records so I have to make a while loop to go through each records and make corresponding AJAX call. I need to pass data from while loop to subsequent AJAX call.

I want to print the console like:

```html
First
Second
Third

First
Second
Third

First
Second
Third

All Asyc Call complete
```

However, it is showing me

```html
First
First
First

All Asyc Call complete

Second
Second
Second

Third
Third
Third
```

```js
// First Ajax Call
$.ajax({
  
  success: function(response1) {
    
    while(response1.next()) {
    
      console.log("First");
      
      // Second Ajax Call
      $.ajax({
        
        success: function(response2){
          
          while(response2.next()) {
          
            console.log("Second");
            
            // Third Ajax Call
            $.ajax({
              
              success: function(response3){
              
                while(response3.next()) {
                  console.log("Third");
                }
                
              }
              
            })
            
            
          }
        
        }
        
      })
    
    }
      
      
  }

})
console.log("All Asyc call completes");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    if( ajax_sucess_counter == 3 ) alert('the 3 ajax calls are completed');
});

var ajax_sucess_counter = 0;

$.ajax({
    //...
    success: function(){
        // ...
        ajax_sucess_counter++;
    }
});
```

Using deferred objects:

```
$.when( $.ajax('call1.php'), $.ajax('call2.php'), $.ajax('call3.php') ).done(function() {
      alert('the 3 ajax calls are completed');
}});
```

You have all information and more examples at [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

Comment: I have heard this can be done using jquery promises and deferred. Can you suggest on this?